# nullable enum parameter always null odata 4 web api 2.2

Tags: asp.net-web-api, enums, null, odata, odatalib

Following the claim here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2014/07/03/odatalib-6-5-0-release.aspx

> Fix bugs for enum  1) ODataUriParser should support nullable Enum as a
>   function parameter.

I upgraded from odata 3 and webapi 2 (a massive time cost due to removal of datetime support ! and various other issues with the upgrade)

And sure enough I can pass null correctly to my function. However - whatever I pass arrives at the function as null !

i.e.

**Request**

> http://visits.backend/odata/Test(PastState=Data.Entities.PastVisitState'Completed')

**WebApiConfig**

```
var functionTest = builder.Function("Test")
       .Returns<bool>();
        functionTest.Parameter<PastVisitState?>("PastState");
```

**WebApp.Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
    [ODataRoute("Test(PastState={pastState})")]
    [EnableQuery]
    public bool Test([FromODataUri] PastVisitState? pastState)
    {
        if (pastState != null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

If its not nullable the value comes through just fine.

**N.B.s**

I just upgraded the nuget package odataLib to 6.8.1 to make sure (was previously as that per linked post on 6.5.0) Same behavior.

I have tested with nullable int and all works fine

I have tried with Nullable also - no joy.

Seems like a bug with Microsoft.OData.Core.dll ?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in the Web API.

In the [ODataModelBinderProvider.cs](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#OData/src/System.Web.OData/OData/Formatter/ODataModelBinderProvider.cs),
The following codes:

```
Type enumType = TypeHelper.GetUnderlyingTypeOrSelf(type);
object[] parameters = new[] { valueString, Enum.ToObject(**type**, 0) };
```

should be changed as:

```
Type enumType = TypeHelper.GetUnderlyingTypeOrSelf(type);
object[] parameters = new[] { valueString, Enum.ToObject(**enumType**, 0) };
```

We have fixed it and the fix will be available in the coming nightly build.

Comment: Great, thanks @sam appreciated any idea when it will be in a stable build / when the next stable release is due?

Comment: Now, it can be available in the nightly build.